# How to increment alphabetic characters from AA to ZZ?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to increment alphabetic characters from AA to ZZ.

The one I created is capable of incrementing alphabetic characters from A to Z.

I only need from AA to ZZ. I will use them as search terms in a webpage to populate results.

```vb
Sub GetAlphabets()
    Dim myvar$, I&
        
    For I = 65 To 90
        myvar = Chr(I)
        Debug.Print myvar
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you need this for? What is your use case?

Comment: Use them as search terms in a webpage in order to populate results.

Comment: Do you want the complete sequence to start with A .. Z and then be followed by AA .. ZZ, or do you only want AA .. ZZ?

Comment: Nope. Only from `AA` to `ZZ`.

Comment: @MITHU fyi posted alternative with one loop only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a second loop

```
Sub GetAlphabets()
    Dim myvar As String
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    
    For I = 65 To 90
        For J = 65 To 90
            myvar = Chr(I) & Chr(J)
            Debug.Print myvar
        Next J
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont see why J is needed, cant you just reuse I?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers It's a nested loop you need the inner to do a full loop for each iteration of the outer loop so you need two variables.

Comment: lol. I must have been half asleep, I get it now. The code just looked repetitive..

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative via column addresses**

The following example call needs only one loop to show all combinations:

```
Sub AA2ZZ()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 27 * 26             ' i.e. 1 * 26 for single chars, 26 * 26 for pairs
    Debug.Print i, Split((Columns(i).Address(, 0)), ":")(0)
Next i
End Sub
```